# Exclamation mark on table or view object in SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle, view, oracle-sqldeveloper

I use Oracle SQL developer https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqldeveloper-landing.html to model my tables and views.
When I create view I see warning symbol next to view element:

[image: warning symbol next to table]

My code for view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW cards_restaurants AS
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                l.loyaltycardid,
                COUNT(r.restaurants_id) AS times_purchased,
                nvl(SUM(p.price), 0)    AS money_spent
            FROM
                loyalty_cards  l
                LEFT JOIN orders         o ON o.loyaltycardid = l.loyaltycardid
                LEFT JOIN restaurants    r ON r.restaurants_id = o.restaurants_id
                LEFT JOIN order_products op ON op.orderid = o.orders_id
                LEFT JOIN products       p ON p.products_id = op.products_id
            GROUP BY
                l.loyaltycardid
        )
    WHERE
        money_spent > 0
    ORDER BY
        money_spent DESC;
```

QUESTION: Where can I check what error my query has? And why when I press "test query" it shows results and that query is successful.

Maybe a full screen picture could help:

[image: Oracle SQL developer window]

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't mean there's an error. It means we haven't parsed the SQL under the view...because it's expensive, and you could have hundreds of those when you do an import from your data dictionary.

[I talk about this here](https://%20https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/01/modeling-view-dependencies-in-sql-developer-data-modeler/)

Right click on the view, select 'parse' - then the picture will update and you'll see a list of tables your view is hitting.

*Disclaimer: I'm a product manager at Oracle, and Data Modeler is one of my products.*

Comment: I right click on the view press "Parse SQL" and nothing changes

Comment: looking at the picture you shared it might be something else, we see the tables but not the columns, if you do the 'validate' what happens?